# Setting a template for all actions of a controller using local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template, local.xml

I have created a custom module `create/routing`, with a controller `RoutingController.php` which has several actions `index, upload, instagram` and I would like to update the template for all of these actions to a custom file `page/routing.phtml` within my `local.xml`

For the `customer/account` module I would write:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

However following the same method for my own module:

```
<create_routing>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/routing.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</create_routing>
```

Does not change the template for any action.

I have also tried `<create_routing_default />` and I know the `setTemplate` method works as if I add it directly to an action i.e. `<create_routing_index />` the template is correctly updated.

I must be missing something fundamental here, do I need to declare something within my module to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there.

By default they will not look in create_routing. You still need to add something to each action handle like so;

```
<create_routing_index>
    <update handle="create_routing" />
</create_routing_index>
```

This will inherit the xml declared in create_routing. You will need to do the same for each action.

The alternative is to programatically add another handle (create_routing) to the layout in an abstract function called by each of the controller actions. I prefer the xml route though.

Comment: Thanks @Smartie this works and is a little neater than my example, do you have any more info on that abstract function you mentioned, I have had a look through the `AccountController` for `customer/account` but cant see anything at a glance?

Comment: If you look through app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml you will also see Magento using the xml way as above with <update handle="customer_account"/>