# Magento 1 layout xml reference all controller's actions

Tags: layout, xml

I need to add into head custom css file, but it should be applied only for admin pages that are inside my extension.

So I don't need this:

```
<default> 
    <reference name="head">      
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>company_module/css/styles.css</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

but I need this:

```
<adminhtml_section_one_index> 
    <reference name="head">      
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>company_module/css/styles.css</name></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_section_one_index>
<adminhtml_section_one_edit> 
    <reference name="head">      
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>company_module/css/styles.css</name></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_section_one_edit>
...
```

This is obvisouly not a nice solution because there will be 10+ different controller actions. Is there any way to match the whole controller or module?

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** Go to `skin/adminhtml/default/default` and place your file under `module/custom.css`

**Step2:** Go to `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout` and create the file `module.xml` with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <name>module/custom.css</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**Step3:** Now connect your xml file to the module in `Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
...
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <namespace_module>
                <file>module.xml</file>
            </namespace_module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
...
</config>
```

Comment: I am not sure if you understand my question properly. I know how to add custom layout and css. But my problem is because I want to use custom css only for sections that are related to my module and not entire admin. `<default>` will affect entire admin. Other option I have is to use each controller action as section for reference. But this is not good solution because I will need to repeat `<reference name="head">` for each controller action. Please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83152/setting-a-template-for-all-actions-of-a-controller-using-local-xml).

I can not update layout for all controller actions together, but what could be done to minimize repeated code is to use `<update handle="handle_name" />`.